# How can I make an input go to that file

Tags: javascript, html, css, file, input

I was wondering how it would be possible to take an HTML input and with javascript make it so that if the user enters 1.html in the input it will take them to the file 1.html?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rough illustration but should give you the general idea. There's a lot you'd want to add to this but I figure you just want a starting point.

```
<form>
<input type='text' class='path'>
<input type='button' class='btn' value='Go!'>
</form>

<script>
    let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    let inputPath = document.querySelector('.path');
    
    // redirect to chosen path
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        location.href = inputPath.value;
    });
</script>
```

You may also wish to consult the [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object docs.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to wrap your inputs in a `<form>` element, to comply with semantics. :)

Comment: Fair point. My answer was a tad rough and ready. You'd really also want a whole host of other things like checking the input is valid etc. too but figured the person asking could work those bits out.